# "Since" of "after" when talking about something in past?

Tags: grammar, past-simple

> ...50 years after the beginning of his career

or

> ...50 years since the beginning of his career

Lets suppose that we are talking about someone whose career is endede already, or someone who has died long ago. Should we use **since** or **after** here? Or some other word?

Answer (score 0):

We don't use *since* to modify a time like this, except in constructions like *It is now 50 years since the beginning of his career*.

In any other context, only *after* works .